# constant class member not constant - C++

Tags: c++, constants

I wonder when I pass a value to a constant variable, why this variable can change.

```
#include <cstdio>

struct point
{
    int x, y, z;
};

class A
{
    public:
        A(const point &p) :
           p(p)
        {
             printf("(%d,%d,%d)\n", p.x, p.y, p.z);
        }

        void do_smth()
        {
            printf("(%d,%d,%d)\n", p.x, p.y, p.z);
        }

        const point &p;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    point p = {1, 1, 1};
    A a(p);
    p.y = 4;
    a.do_smth();
    return 0;
}
```

stdout:

```
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 4, 1)
```

I use g++ v4.7 with no extra arguments to compile this code.

Comment: const point &p; is a definiton of a constant reference. so the reference is constant not the value.and so u can assign it to whatever u want

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the `Point` inside the `A` class is constant, but as it's a *reference* to `p` which it *not* constant, you can change `p` as much as you like and the all references to `p` will change as well. To simplify, references are just a kind of fancy pointer.

Answer (score 4):

`p` itself is not const. `A.p` is... Referencing a non-`const` variable with a `const` reference doesn't magically make it `const`.

Answer (score 1):

`const` means that the value cannot change *through this reference*, not that it will not change at all.

Answer (score 0):

You change the variable in place, where it is not constant. You cannot change it in `do_smth()` method, try it.

Passing to some class as constant doesn't change the object at all.